# How can I follow my Facebook Friends on Twitter?

Tags: facebook, twitter, contacts

When I log into Facebook in the News Feed it shows some of my friends posting via Twitter. Is there a way I can automatically follow them on my Twitter account or get all their twitter ids to follow ?

Right now I am just trying to see if they used their real names and using the [Find people](http://twitter.com/invitations/find_on_twitter) on Twitter feature. By experience in twitter though, I know some do not use their Real Names :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Power Twitter](http://powertwitter.me/) has a Facebook feature.

Comment: Cool ! I will check it out ! Can you post their link please :)

Comment: Okay I am following up been searching forums and everything. Does that Facebook show those who update their status to facebook ? Because alot of people in that stream are not my friends. I like it though

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I looked at it again,  my mistake I was clicking the tweets that were propagating from the home timeline, did not realize the loading was still `Loading...` It has been 15 minutes and it is still loading. I am just going to assume that one of the plugins is messing with it :(